# Is there any reason to test Difference-in-Differences if paralell trend is weakly violated?

Tags: difference-in-difference

Normally when testing the parallel trend assumption in the Difference-in-Differences setting, we normally conduct the joint null test for the coefficients of pre-treatment periods. Normally, while the p-value of this test is higher than 0.1, so the parallel is satisfied. I am wondering if p-value of this test is 0.0979, whether I have any reason to conduct the Difference-in-Differences test?

Comment: I would suggest not using p-value thresholds rigidly, and this applies to any statistical procedure, not just DID. The difference between .1 and 0.0979 is unlikely to be itself statistically significant. The magnitude of the effects also matters. If they are tiny, the bias may be quite small and you can proceed. The details of the setting also matter. Is making a type I error costly? Finally, I have not come across 0.1 as a standard. Can you provide a source?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov From my understanding, I think 0,1 should be the benchmark to say the parallel assumption being violated that joint null tests of coefficients pre-event is insignificant, meaning there is no significant difference between treatment and control group before event date. Please let me now if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Personally speaking, which benchmark you normally use for testing parallel trend, can I ask ?

Comment: From [Miller,2021][https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10940-021-09513-w], he said that "If the common trends assumption holds, the joint null tests of coefficients will be zero for all relative time periods before BWC acquisition (from j = −8 to −2), based on a joint null test". So, I explain that when the p-value of the joint null test of coefficients before event date higher than 0,1, we cannot reject the null hypothesis that" There is no difference between control and treatment group before event date" => parallel trend assumption being satisfied.

Comment: I use a p-value that depends on the cost of Type I error for what I am doing. If doing the treatment when there is no effect is bad, I use a small one. If I have lots of pre-periods, I use a smaller threshold too. Finally, a large p-value does not mean there is no difference in trends. It just means you cannot detect one with the data you have.